# Javascript Plotly box plot issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, plotly

I want to display a box plot using **Plotly Javascript** library.
I set the type of chart *box* but it shows a line.

```
var data = [
  {
    y: [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21],
    boxpoints: 'all',
    jitter: 0.3,
    pointpos: -1.8,
    type: 'box'
  }
];

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3aL3985y/)

Answer (score 0):

Box plots are not part of the basic plotlyjs bundle.

You'll need to upgrade to [plotlyjs advanced](https://plot.ly/javascript/#advanced-charts).